# Find the in between value within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have the following dataframe:

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | -1 |
| 3 | -1 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | -1 |
| 6 | -1 |
| 7 | -1 |
| 8 | 10 |

All those value equal to -1 means N/A and the value should be increasing. Therefore I would like to generate another two columns that should indicate the possible min and possible max value, and the possible min and max is based on the valid value inside the value column.

The exptected output would be like this:

| index | value | possible min | possible max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 1 | -1 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | -1 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | -1 | 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |  |  |
| 5 | -1 | 6 | 10 |
| 6 | -1 | 6 | 10 |
| 7 | -1 | 6 | 10 |
| 8 | 10 |  |  |

I would use the extra column to find the fillna value using my own matching logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `df`:

```
   value
0      1
1     -1
2     -1
3     -1
4      6
5     -1
6     -1
7     -1
8     10
```

If something should mean `NaN`, make it `NaN`.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].replace(-1, np.nan)
```

Now, we can fill your desired values:

```
df.loc[df['value'].isna(), 'possible_min'] = df['value'].ffill()
df.loc[df['value'].isna(), 'possible_max'] = df['value'].bfill()
print(df)
```

Bonus, linear interpolation:

```
df['interpolated'] = df['value'].interpolate()
```

Output:

```
   value  possible_min  possible_max  interpolated
0    1.0           NaN           NaN          1.00
1    NaN           1.0           6.0          2.25
2    NaN           1.0           6.0          3.50
3    NaN           1.0           6.0          4.75
4    6.0           NaN           NaN          6.00
5    NaN           6.0          10.0          7.00
6    NaN           6.0          10.0          8.00
7    NaN           6.0          10.0          9.00
8   10.0           NaN           NaN         10.00
```

Comment: Good answer, especially with the bonus interpolation :)

Comment: Thanks for the interpolation. But that is the part that I need to use custom method.

Comment: There are many interpolation methods available, I'd be surprised if one of them didn't align with whatever you're planning.

Comment: Actually the data is time series, and the so-called value is the geo data point. First of all the time series is filtered and therefore it is not linear at all, as interpolation assume the data point is linear in time series and thus this is not applicable. Therefore we need to set the possible min max value and then use another method to figure out the exact location.

Comment: But really thanks for your interpolated method. If finally some data points can't be figured out then eventually I would need to use the interpolated method.

Comment: Interpolation in no way only assumes the data point is linear... unless you're specifically using linear interpolation, which happens to be the default. Look at `method` in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)